# In rails I enter the list action, it gives me a error about show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys, I'm new to Rails. I'm very confused about this problem I have right now. When I hit the `http://localhost:3000/videos/list` it gives me an error about not specifying the show action.

Here's my code

```
# routes.rb

Drumvideo::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :videos
end


# videos_controller.rb

class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @videos = Video.order("videos.updated_at DESC")
  end
end


# list.erb.html

<% @videos.each do |video| %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= video.title %></li>
    <li><%= video.desc %></li>
    <li><%= video.tudou %></li>
    <li><%= video.drummers.first.first_name %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

I think the problem is in the resources routes, But I don't know exactly how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

change your `routes.rb` to

```
Drumvideo::Application.routes.draw do |map|
  resources :videos, :collection => {
    :list => :get
  }
end
```

Comment: I think that the OP should be using the index action for this, not the list action. The list action is old tech.

Answer (score 0):

The list action is very old in Rails and is not use any more. Whatever is recommending that you use it is outdated and should not be trusted.

Instead, read the Getting Started guide for how to properly use Rails now: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html